# How to extract nested field from Envelop type schema in s3 sink connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, s3-kafka-connector

Avro schema :

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Envelope",
  "namespace": "test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "before",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "Value",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "id",
              "type": {
                "type": "long",
                "connect.default": 0
              },
              "default": 0
            },
            {
              "name": "createdAt",
              "type": [
                "null",
                {
                  "type": "string",
                  "connect.version": 1,
                  "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.ZonedTimestamp"
                }
              ],
              "default": null
            },
           
          ],
          "connect.name": "test.Value"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "after",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "Value"
      ],
      "default": null
    }
   
  ],
  "connect.name": "test.Envelope"
}
```

S3-sink connector configuration:

```
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
  "s3.region": "us-west-2",
  "flush.size": "1",
  "tasks.max": "3",
  "timezone": "UTC",
  "locale": "US",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "aws.access.key.id": "---",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "s3.bucket.name": "test-s3-sink-created-at-partition",
  "partition.duration.ms": "1000",
  "topics.regex": "test_topic",
  "aws.secret.access.key": "---",
  "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "s3-sink-created-at-partition",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "path.format": "YYYY/MM/dd",
  "timestamp.extractor": "RecordField",
  "timestamp.field": "createdAt"
}
```

Error:

```
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:591)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:326)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: The field 'createdAt' does not exist in
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Unable to find nested field 'createdAt'
```

---

Problem facing:

Currently, I am trying to get data from test-topic using above sink connector using createAt field in s3 bucket but it continuously throwing error for createdAt field.
And s3-bucket is not created using above configuration.
Please provide your suggestions on this.

Comment: Btw, you should set flush.size greater than 1. Otherwise, you'll end up with one Kafka record per file and have really slow S3 reads and pay a lot for every bucket scan (also move your aws keys to environment variables rather than plaintext)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @OneCricketeer much appreciated. Will increase the size once resolve this createdAt issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `after.Value.createdAt` - [See my PR](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/pull/48)

But the better option is to [unwrap the envelope](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html), like you're asking.

> s3-bucket is not created using above configuration

You need to create the bucket ahead of time.

Comment: These properties we can use in Debezium source connector. I need to extract createdAt field using sink connector, so I can read data from topic and write into s3 bucket using createdAt field. Could you please suggest me sink properties.

Comment: As answered, `"timestamp.field": "after.Value.createdAt"` at the sink , **but** I think you should unwrap the after state, so then you'd want `"timestamp.field": "Value.createdAt"`

Comment: Tried to use above approach but it is not working in sink connector properties.Could you please suggest what I am missing here. Thank you.

Comment: You tried both? Can you edit the question to include both attempts? And the errors they display? I don't think you're missing anything. The only reason you may get that error is if some records in your topic do not contain that field path

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Few records didn't containing createdAt .Thank you for the help.